# What is web3.currentprovider?

Tags: web3js

I am new to smart contract development and I would like to know what is "web3.currentProvider". Can you explain me very simply what it is please?

I've already looked at the documentation but I don't really understand.

Comment: It is the connection point to the blockchain, the value is usually the url of the client node that run the blockchain and offer a connection

Answer (score 1):

Only Ethereum nodes are able to execute transactions or request information from the blockchain. The provider is a service that directly communicates with Ethereum nodes to fetch or send information to the blockchain.

Whenever Web3 needs to access the Ethereum blockchain (e.g. sending a transaction) a request is made to a provider that directly forwards the request to a blockchain node.

Without a provider, Web3 has no way to communicate with the blockchain. Providers act as bridges between Web3 and Ethereum nodes.

Comment: I would like, but i just have 11 reputation, need 15